# Ninject.MVC3 - NinjectWebCommon RegisterServices System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using the [Ninject.MVC3 NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3/) and [NinjectWebCommon RegisterServices](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application#nuget-package).  This is my service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private string someDir;

    public MyService(string someDir)
    {
        this.someDir = someDir;
    }
    ...
}
```

One of the services has a constructor parameter that I want to inject with a value from Server.MapPath, but System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null.

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var server = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server;

        kernel
            .Bind<IMyService>()
            .To<MyService>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("someDir", server.MapPath("~/someDir/"));
     }
     ...
}
```

I guessing that HttpContext.Current is null because ASP.NET hasn't done what it needs to do yet, but my question is

can I use constructor injection here, or do I need some other way of injecting this path, like an Init method or method injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegisterServices is called at application start time, before there is any context even created.  It's also only done once, when the worker process starts.

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure if internally it relies on the HttpContext, but you might try

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/someDir/");
```

Looking at the decompiled source, it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the full path in the web.config/app settings then for each environment have a config transform that changes it.

Comment: That won't help if he's in a hosted environment, since he might not know what the path is.  And they could change it on you without telling you.